# Can this selection sort implementation be made more efficient or elegant?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have made a basic implementation of Selection sort, using Math.min() of javascript. Can anyone point out ways in which one can make this more efficient or elegant? Something that I could have avoided doing, etc? Thanks everyone, the code is below:

```
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 9, 0, 10, 2, 14, 8];

function selectionSort(array) {
  let workingArr = [...array]; //don't want to modify original array
  let sortedArr = []; //this will be returned as result

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
    let sliced = workingArr.slice(0); 
    let min = Math.min(...sliced); //minimum of the slice
    sortedArr[i] = min; 
    let index = workingArr.indexOf(min);
    workingArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return sortedArr; 
}

let x = selectionSort(arr);
console.log(x);
document.body.innerHTML = x;
```

Comment: Did the answer below help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the definition of selection sort being used here but here you have two versions of your code where: 1) you remove unnecessary copies of arrays (space inefficient) and 2) you have a more elegant solution.

**Your original solution optimised**

```
function selectionSort(array) {
  const localArr = [...array];
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < localArr.length; i++) { 
    const min = Math.min(...localArr);                                  
    localArr.splice(localArr.indexOf(min), 1);
    i--;
    res.push(min);
  }
  return res;
}
```

**Use `Array.prototype.reduce`**

```
function selectionSort(array) {
  const localArr = [...array];
  return array.reduce((acc) => { 
    const min = Math.min(...localArr);                                 
    localArr.splice(localArr.indexOf(min), 1);
    return acc.concat(min);
  }, []);
}
```

Note: in your original version of the function you seemed to care about immutability. Then in the body of the function you use `Array.prototype.splice` and `Array.prototype.push` which both contravene the FP principle of immutability. **I am not using a pure FP approach here** just for brevity but you should look into other arrays methods that are more 'reliable' so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

It seems nobody found anything here. But I finally found something that could have been avoided in original code. I figured out that there is no need to make slices of the array named workingArr in code above (in the question). Here is the modified code which is simpler.

```
let arr = [2, 0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 9, 0, 10, 2, 14, 8];

function selectionSort(array) {
  let workingArr = [...array]; //don't want to modify original array
  let sortedArr = []; //this will be returned as result

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //run upto full length of original array
    let min = Math.min(...workingArr); //minimum of the slice
    sortedArr[i] = min; //minimum found inserted into sortedArr
    let index = workingArr.indexOf(min); //find inserted ele's position in original input array's copy, so that we can use it to removed ele from that same array (otherwise in next pass that element will still come out as min)
    workingArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return sortedArr; //return resulting array
}

let x = selectionSort(arr);
console.log(x);

console.log(x.reverse()); //for descending sort
```